# Does optimal posture change depending on the speed of a run?

Tags: running, posture

So for some time I had incorporated approximately 1 hour run into my workout during which I covered 10~12 km. Since I was running on a threadmill with a constant elevation (2~2.5) I was adviced to run in inclined position so my body is leaning forward anywhere up to approximately 15 degrees keeping my back straight.

About a year ago, I started working out more intensively with free weights and I couldnt combine that long of a run with strength training. I, therefore, had an idea of doing a 15 minutes short run as a warm up. To, hopefully, not loose much stamina I split the 15 minute run into 5 minutes at moderate pace (10-11kmh), 4 minutes of faster pace (13-14kmh) and 1 minute of fast pace (17-18kmh) with a minute or so to cool down after.

I was using this routine since then and could not ignore the fact that with a faster pace it's very hard to maintain that inclined forward leaning posture. In fact, when running at 18kmh I only manage to run with a more upright stance where my chest is forward while legs and upper torso are more backward.

Now, I was told that forward leaning posture is optimal as it helps with not overloading your back when running uphill as well as being more efficent in terms of energy consumption. Is the same true for the faster paces? Or is the posture my body instinctively takes ok?

Comment: Who told you this and why did you buy it unquestioned?

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking An aquatiance of mine who is far more dedicated to running. I had some ankle and lower back pain so I asked for a technique advice and that was his reccomendation. The argument seemed sound to me, as I know that posture can matter a lot in martial arts where by using your bone structure you can drastically reduce the amount of force you need to resist a push or a ull. Something along the lines by leaning you do displace centre of mass and redirect the gravity towards forward movement"didnt seem so farfetched.

Comment: The only science I know mentions low cadence (strides per minute) as a main contributor to injuries and pain, since too long a step takes a much heavier toll on the tissues. Leaning forward contributes to higher cadence but is not necessary for it. Posture generally is autonomously corrected through several reflex loops, even though it can, in theory, be learned differently. Whether this is positive is another thing. Maybe there are people having more specific knowledge on that particular question though.